# zoom-in ? content != 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with a problem in one of my projects...

By default my content container is 100% but when I'm zoom-in the container become smaller than 100%

first img:

[image: normal zoom]

second img:

[image: zoomed in]

Here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body_wrap">
            <header>
                <!-- content -->
            </header>

            <section class="main">
                <div class="content_wrapper">
                    <div class="content clearfix">
                        <!-- content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
}
html { height: 100% }
body { font-size: 62.5%; line-height: 1 }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none }
a { text-decoration: none; }

::-moz-selection {background:#E92C6C; color:#fff; text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);}
::selection {background:#E92C6C; color:#fff; text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);}
*, textarea:focus, input:focus { outline: none; }
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;visibility: hidden;overflow: hidden}

body {
    background: #FF0000 url('http://wallpapers.wallbase.cc/rozne/wallpaper-3027963.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0%;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

section.main {position: relative;width: 100%;background: #FFF;z-index: 5;min-height: 890px;}
section.main .content_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.7image.ru/pics/1113/406472675.png') repeat-x;
    top: -10px;
}
section.main .content_wrapper .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px; 
    padding: 20px 0; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have your `header` set to `width: 960px`. This is causing the page to be extended horizontally when you zoom in and the width of the screen becomes less than `960px`. Set your `body-wrap` div to `overflow: hidden`, so that your `header` no longer `overflows` your `body-wrap`.

Comment: i do not mind if the scroll bar appear... my problem is the container when it become smaller than 100%

Comment: The container is still 100%, 100% of the window width. If you want it to be 100% of document, wrap everything in a div with position:relative; should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
section.main .content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

How about using:

```
section.main .content_wrapper {
    width: inherit;
}
```

It helped me with a lot of my projects, would help you too.